# Custom Web Service for xcelsius

Tags: xcelsius

I am involved with a team that uses Xcelsius for their dashboard presentation design. I know of options provided by SAP to connect to the database. My team used flynet but lisence issues are pushing us to think of custom webservice. Can design a custom webservice (C# or Java) and use it with Xcelsius. I will realy like to know if its worth it or there are better options for my team. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I was recently involved with an engagement that built out custom web services to both write new and alter existing records in the database.  This was the only option for us as SAP does not provide any viable options to write back out of the box.  Also, I don't think they (SAP) should but this was a unique requirement that necessitated the workflow.

The web services were in .net

Comment: Thanks, though I left the team now but I still want to know. With your custom web service what you use for reporting, is it also custom built or Xcelsius. Also is your web service SOAP or RESTful. Thanks again